# asset helper for a path without filename for use within scss variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline, font-awesome

I am trying to get my font-awesome to work.

After a lot of searching and fiddling I have come this far:

I precompiled for production and my fonts are appearing under 
/public/assets/font-awesome/fonts

Now I have following variable in a scss file which does not work in heroku since the variable points to the wrong directory. This does work on development.

```
$fa-font-path:        "../fonts" !default;
```

When I change it to following it works on heroku (production) but not on development.

```
$fa-font-path:        "font-awesome/fonts" !default;
```

I am using an **scss file** and I need **an scss helper** to get the path (without the filename and extension) in this variable. **How can I do this??**

I have been searching like a madman for this but I cannot find how to get the path without the filename and extension

Answer (score 1):

In your production.rb, did you happen to set config.serve_static_files = true?

Comment: Yes, I have followed The instructions on heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline what does this setting do?